# How can I find duplicate in the first column, then remove concerning whole lines ?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, duplicate, uniq

I have one xlsx file (110725x9 matrix) and I saved as type text (tab delemited) because I don't know whether Unix helps for xlsx files or not. Duplicates rows are always successive line by line.

For example, suppose text file as follow. You will see 3,4-th, 7,8-th and 17,18-th rows are same. I'd like to remove upper duplicate lines not lower always.

```
2009,37214611872    2009    135 20  17,1    17,4    19,2    21,8    24,1
2009,37237442922    2009    135 22  16,5    14,5    12,6    11,2    10,5
2009,37260273973    2009    136 0   7,7     7,2     7,1     7,3     7,5
2009,37260273973    2009    136 0   7,7     7,2     7,0     7,2    7,4
2009,37488584475    2009    136 20  14,6    15,1    16,4    18,3    20,1
2009,37511415525    2009    136 22  15,9    14,6    12,8    10,9    9,4
2009,37534246575    2009    137 0   8,2     6,9     6,2     6,2     6,4
2009,37534246575    2009    137 0   8,1     6,8     6,1     6,0     6,3
2009,37557077626    2009    137 2   6,8     6,7     6,5     6,3     6,2
2009,37579908676    2009    137 4   5,8     5,6     5,4     5,4     5,7
2009,37602739726    2009    137 6   6,3     6,1     5,9     5,8     5,8
2009,37625570776    2009    137 8   4,5     5,2     6,0     6,6     7,2
2009,37648401826    2009    137 10  9,6     9,0     8,4     8,4     9,1
2009,37671232877    2009    137 12  11,4    11,7    12,4    13,4    14,4
2009,37694063927    2009    137 14  12,4    13,1    14,2    15,4    16,7
2009,37785388128    2009    137 22  15,5    14,0    12,2    10,3    8,7
2009,37808219178    2009    138 0   6,3     5,8     5,5     5,5     5,8
2009,37808219178    2009    138 0   6,2     5,7     5, 4    5,4     5,7
```

So output should be like that:

```
2009,37214611872    2009    135 20  17,1    17,4    19,2    21,8    24,1
2009,37237442922    2009    135 22  16,5    14,5    12,6    11,2    10,5
2009,37260273973    2009    136 0   7,7     7,2     7,0     7,2    7,4
2009,37488584475    2009    136 20  14,6    15,1    16,4    18,3    20,1
2009,37511415525    2009    136 22  15,9    14,6    12,8    10,9    9,4
2009,37534246575    2009    137 0   8,1     6,8     6,1     6,0     6,3
2009,37557077626    2009    137 2   6,8     6,7     6,5     6,3     6,2
2009,37579908676    2009    137 4   5,8     5,6     5,4     5,4     5,7
2009,37602739726    2009    137 6   6,3     6,1     5,9     5,8     5,8
2009,37625570776    2009    137 8   4,5     5,2     6,0     6,6     7,2
2009,37648401826    2009    137 10  9,6     9,0     8,4     8,4     9,1
2009,37671232877    2009    137 12  11,4    11,7    12,4    13,4    14,4
2009,37694063927    2009    137 14  12,4    13,1    14,2    15,4    16,7
2009,37785388128    2009    137 22  15,5    14,0    12,2    10,3    8,7
2009,37808219178    2009    138 0   6,2     5,7     5, 4    5,4     5,7
```

How can I do that without sorting?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you not want to use `sort` for this?  The whole thing can be accomplished in a simple line of `sort input-file | uniq -w 16 > output-file`.  Again, this is only curiosity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove duplicates based on a single column, you can use `awk`:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' input-file > output-file
```

You can see an explanation for this in [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30181/70524).

Removing the older lines is more complicated. Given that duplicates always come together, you can do:

```
awk 'prev && ($1 != prev) {print seen[prev]} {seen[$1] = $0; prev = $1} END {print seen[$1]}' input-file > output-file
```

Here, in the middle block, `{seen[$1] = $0}` saves the current line (`$0`) to the `seen` array with the first field (`$1`) as index, then saves the first field in the `prev` variable. This `prev` is used in the first block when processing the next line.

In the first block, then, we check if `prev` is set (only true for the second line onwards) and not equal to the *current* first field (here `prev` was set while processing the previous line). If it isn't, we have moved past duplicates and can print the previous line. At the `END`, we do that again for the last line.

Comment: This code removed lower duplicates. I need to remove upper duplicates not lower dupplicates.

Comment: @SuatYazıcı see update.

Comment: If removing lower duplicates is easier, a possible "solution" for removing upper duplicates is `tac | awk [remove lower duplicates] | tac` :-)

Comment: @muru awk: line 1: syntax error at or near }

Comment: @egmont As far as I see, tac command is similar to cat command in reverse but I didn't succeed anything for now.

Comment: @muru I got error when I use your code. " awk: line 1: syntax error at or near}"

Comment: @SuatYazıcı ah, sorry, I copied the wrong command from history. Added the correct one now.

Comment: @muru It works very well now. Can you give me explanation again in detail ? Because I have diffucultly in understanding owing to not using awk before.

Comment: @SuatYazıcı then you'll have to study a bit of awk. I cannot teach details of awk syntax in an answer.

Comment: Make sense :) Thx for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Using tac and uniq.

```
$ tac text.txt | uniq -w 16 | tac
```

Comment: Could you extend your answer, explaining how it solves the problem?